# Drop down using jquery doesn't drop on click [small screen sizes]

Tags: jquery, magento-1.9

I've recently implemented a new menu using jquery. it works fine on Firefox/ Chrome etc. but doesn't response to click in screen sizes less than 900 [for example kindle silk // resize firefox to mobile view].

**my menu**

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">T-shirts</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><h4>Gender</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Ladies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Men's</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><h4>Colour</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
/*global $ */

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');

    $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });

    $(".menu > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").show();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Please create an example of the issue you are encountered with in "codepen.io" or "jsfiddle.net". Without an with the issue, people will ignore your question. Please also add your CSS code related to the rest of your code.